# Check if user refreshed, went back, closed browser etc.. socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an application where I use socket.io alongside node.js. I can't find / figure out a way to check for events when users leave application i.e. close browser, refresh page, go back etc.. every one is connected in specific room. I need to know when someone leaves the room, know what their socket.io id was etc.. is there a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a user destroys the JS context by changing page (going back or forward, refreshing, closing the browser, etc), the Socket.io connection is closed, and that's how you get to know that (listen for the `.on('disconnect')` event on the *server*).

To deal with rooms, you may want to look at this page: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/